# Retrieve "Variant" data type from Enterprise Architect using DXL

Tags: ole, enterprise-architect, jet, variant, ibm-doors

How can I use the DXL OLE mechanism to fetch a diagram's modification time from *Enterprise Architect 12*?

Details:

I want to retrieve diagrams from EA and integrate them as OLE object into *IBM Rational DOORS 9.5*. This is already working. I intend to compare the modification dates of the EA diagram and the DOORS object before retrieving the diagram to decide if this operation is really needed.

Problem is, EA provides a diagram attribute [*EA.Diagram.ModifiedDate*](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/diagram2.html) which returns the diagram's modification date as data type *Variant*. How can I handle this within DXL? The result parameter for `oleGet()` **can be one of the types `string|int|bool|char|OleAutoObj`**. No structured type (which would probably be `DxlObject`). Neither string nor int parameters contain any useful data after the call -- just null values.

Test code:

```
OleAutoObj  eaRepository, eaProject, eaDiagram
OleAutoObj  eaApp    = oleGetAutoObject("EA.App")
OleAutoArgs autoArgs = create
string      guid     = "{729F140F-9DA4-4ff6-A9B2-75622AD1C22D}"

// connect to an existing EA instance
oleGet (eaApp, "Repository", eaRepository)
oleMethod (eaRepository, "GetProjectInterface", autoArgs, eaProject)

// call EA to a diagram which has this GUID
put(autoArgs, guid)
oleMethod(eaRepository, "GetDiagramByGuid", autoArgs, eaDiagram)
delete autoArgs

// access diagram attributes
string eaModifiedDate // DXL accepts [string|int|bool|char|OleAutoObj] only
oleGet(eaDiagram, "ModifiedDate", eaModifiedDate)
print "ModifiedDate = '" eaModifiedDate"'\n"
```

IBM's *Support Team* (commercial, available for paying customers) couldn't help and suggested to forward this question to the *Service Team* (for extra $s). Rather disappointing.

Comment: I'm using it with Perl and there I have to use `variant->value` to get the contents.

Comment: The OleAutoObj should have a `value` property I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (just guessing :-)

```
OleAutoObj eaModifiedDate
oleGet(diagram, "ModifiedDate", eaModifiedDate)
if (null eaModifiedDate)
    print "no eaModifiedDate\n"
else {
    string diaDate
    oleGet(eaModifiedDate, "Value", diaDate)
    print "ModifiedDate = '" diaDate"'\n"
}
```

If that does not work then here comes the ultimate work around:

```
string err
string result

put(autoArgs, "SELECT ModifiedDate FROM t_diagram WHERE ea_guid = '"  guid  "'")
err = oleMethod (eaRepository, "SQLQuery", autoArgs, result)
if (!null err)
    print "ERROR: " err "\n"
delete autoArgs

print "result= '" result"'\n"
```

This will return a XML formatted string (!) which contains the date in the format you like.

**Edit 1**: Turns out that EA's SQLQuery is buggy and returns just the date. Since Perl deals with OLE Variants in a similar way I found this code snippet:

```
my $dia = $rep->getdiagrambyguid("{63EFF3FA-0D5C-4986-AC0A-C723D2F755E3}");
my $value = $dia->ModifiedDate->Value;
print $value->Date( 'yyyy/MM/dd' );
print $value->Time( 'hh:mm:ss' );
```

So the `ModifiedDate` is an ole-object and has a `Date` and a `Time` method. This *should* work with DXL too.

**Edit 2**:Now here's the ulti-ultimate work around even shipping around the cliffs of EA's bug ocean:

```
my $dia = $rep->SQLQuery("SELECT Format (ModifiedDate, \"Short Time\") AS T FROM t_diagram");
```

This will format the date as time string. Works for EAP (aka Mickeysoft Access) according to [this page](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php). Other RDBMS likely have similar functions.

Comment: Problem solved! Using the ulti-ultimate workaround helps. Using `Format (ModifiedDate, \"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss\")` for the query helps DXL to parse the date&time string when converting to `Date` type. Extracting the date&time from the XML result string works using `Regexp fetchDate = regexp2 "<t>(.*)<\\/t>"; if (fetchDate result) result = result [match 1]; delete fetchDate;`. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An update with a few corrections of my statements in comments.

I was wrong. It is *indeed* possible to receive structured data types using the OLE automation interface. As Thomas mentioned, the `OleAutoObject` is the proper DXL return type, `oleGet()` is the proper function. To access the returned object's attributes, it is required to be aware of the "real" data type and to have a look at the [SDK documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/resources/booklets/enterprise_architect_sdk.pdf) in order to know which class attributes are available since DXL is not aware of the data type.

However, in DXL, retrieving the attribute of a structured data type is a bit cumbersone. Example (intended to be appended to the inital post's code):

```
OleAutoObj  diaLinksCollection
int         count    = -1
string      buffer   = ""

// access simple diagram attributes
err = oleGet(eaDiagram, "Version", buffer)      
if (!null err) print "ERROR in Diagram.Version: " err "\n"
print "diagram version = " buffer "\n"

// access structured diagram attribute
err = oleGet(eaDiagram, "DiagramLinks", diaLinksCollection)
if (!null err) print "ERROR in Diagram.DiagramLinks: " err "\n"

err = oleGet(diaLinksCollection, "Count", count)
if (!null err) print "ERROR in Collection.Count: " err "\n"

print "count = " count "\n"
```

Thus, it is indeed possible to execute an SQL query, even if the repository is residing in a plain *.eap file, see Thomas' workaround.

As mentioned, the **`Variant`** data type can not be retrieved using `oleGet()` since this approach returns a NULL result.